# How do I import a character vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a block of text that looks like this: "gatcctccatatacaacggtatctccacctcaggtttagatctca" and it goes on like that for 5000 characters.

I want to import it into R as a character vector. Should I put it in a .rtf file and try to import that file? And what code do I use in order to import it?

Comment: You could also put it into a .txt file and use `myFile <- scan(file=myFile.txt, list(""))`.

Comment: `readLines` should work too

Comment: Assuming this is a DNA sequence, whatever you are trying to do in the long run, it is pretty much guaranteed that there is a better way to do it somewhere in bioconductor. I have a feeling that you don't actually have to separate this into individual letters for whatever you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't really about reading the data into R, it's splitting up the string into individual characters.

Reading it in using either of the answers posted:

```
v <- readLines("your_file.txt")
v <- "gatcc...."
```

Splitting it up, using `strsplit`:

```
v <- strsplit(v, "")[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the text anyway, simply copy it directly into R:

```
v <- "gatcctccatatacaacggtatctccacctcaggtttagatctca"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It only works when I put in characters like this: v <- c("g", "a", "t"). And it would take forever to do that with 5000 characters....

Comment: Ok, I see. You didn't write that you wanted each character being an element of the vector, that's why I thought you simply wanted to import that as a text block.

Answer (score 0):

I would save it as a text file and then load it in using the readLines() functions:

```
character_data <- "your_file.txt"
v<-readLines(character_data)
```

This is a little bit more complicated than copying and pasting but has the advantage of being reproducible for another person if they want to run the code as well as making it easy to change the string later on.